# How to make Carbon subWeekdays() remove holidays in addition to removing weekends

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

How would I be able to modify the subWeekdays() method in Carbon to account for holidays?  For example:

`Carbon::now()->subWeekdays(10)->toDateString();`

goes back ten days not counting weekends.  I would like to be able to do something like the following

`Carbon::now()->subWeekdays(10, true)->toDateString();`

By passing the second argument of `true` it would instruct Carbon to now only ignore weekends, but holidays as well.

Any idea on how I can add the code to Carbon to make this work?

*Or* perhaps add a method to the Carbon library where I can do something like the following and get the same result:

`Carbon::now()->subWeekdays(10)->subHolidays()->toDateString();`

thanks

Comment: How would you define holidays?

Comment: Good question:  I guess I didn't account for that.  Perhaps an array such as this:  `$holidays = ['2017-09-04', '2017-11-23'];`  which would then allow something like either this `Carbon::now()->subWeekdays(10, $holidays, true)->toDateString();`  or something like `Carbon::now()->subWeekdays(10)->subHolidays($holidays)->toDateString();`

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to do this with https://packagist.org/packages/rovangju/carbon-nbd if you're interested

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use CarbonExt\NBD\Calculator;

$calc = new Calculator();
$calc->addExclusion(new Carbon('2017-09-04'));

var_dump(Carbon::now()->subWeekdays(10)->toDateString());  // '2017-08-22'
var_dump($calc->nbd(Carbon::now()->subWeekdays(10))->toDateString());  // '2017-08-23'
```